# i get this error when creating a new project in angular7

Tags: angularjs, api

```
Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...-contrib-clean":"^0.6'
```

i get this error when trying to create a new angular project, i even tried to clear cache and and reinstall ANGULAR CLI ,anyone with who faced this or knows how to resolve this, please help

[here is the screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2eTK.png)

Answer (score 0):

try and run ng new with --skip-npm and later do an npm install,it works for me 9 months laters